# Python 3 exception not printing new line

Tags: python, exception, stderr

I do not really know how to say it, but when I raise exception in python 3.2, '\n' aren't *parsed*...

Here is an example:

```
class ParserError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
            super().__init__(self, message)

try:
    raise ParserError("This should have\na line break")
except ParserError as err:
    print(err)
```

It works like this:

```
$ ./test.py
(ParserError(...), 'This should have\na line break')
```

How do I make sure new lines are printed as new lines?

```
class ParserError(Exception):
    pass
```

or

```
print(err.args[1])
```

Comment: Does print(err.message) do it?

Comment: Nope, object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: Intrestingly, if you get rid of the `__init__` method, just the exception text is printed with your code, and the newline is correctly printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, err.message was deprecated in 2.6 - so no longer present, so...

```
print(err.args[1])
```

Comment: `print(err.args[1])` here, no?

Comment: Sorry. So use to writing py 2.6/2.7 code, I have a brain glitch when trying to write 3.x code!

Comment: I don't understand how this is a solution. The OP wants newlines to be printed when exceptions are raised. Are you saying we have to catch the error and print it properly ourselves? The standard traceback will just never display the message properly?

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that the `repr` of your message string is being printed as part of passing the whole `Exception` object to `print()`, so the newline is being converted back into `\n`. If you individually `print` the actual string, the actual newline will print.

Comment: I mentioned `err.message` but the reply to the comment was "has no attribute"

Comment: When I try `print(err.message)` I get `'ParserError' object has no attribute 'message'`